# Segmentation fault in my Binary Search tree program

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I get a seg fault when I run my program to create a binary search tree. The program is supposed to read in 2 numbers from the user. The first one how many nodes I want to create, and the second is what the head node is. In these nodes, I store a random value from 1 to 10. I am getting a seg fault when I run it, and after running my debugger, it tells me the seg fault is when I go to print the head node. There are probably more errors though, because this is my first time doing a binary search tree. I am going to post my code, and then some sample output that was given. Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct TreeNode_ {
    int value;
    struct TreeNode_ *left;
    struct TreeNode_ *right;
}TreeNode;


TreeNode* insert(TreeNode* node, const int value);
TreeNode* create_node(const int value);
void destroy(TreeNode* node);
void display(TreeNode* node);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("%s is missing parameters\n", argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    const int size = atoi(argv[1]);
    const int root_val = atoi(argv[2]);
    TreeNode* root = NULL;
    int i;
    root = insert(root,root_val);
    printf("Head node is %d\n", root->value);
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int value = rand() % 10 + 1;
        insert(root,value);
    }
    display(root);
    destroy(root);
}

TreeNode *create_node(const int value){
    TreeNode *node;
    node = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    node->value = value;
    node->left = 0;
    node->right = 0;
    return node;
}

void display(TreeNode *node){
    if(node == 0) return;
    if(node->left != 0)
         display(node->left);

    printf("\n%d\n", node->value);

    if(node->right != 0)
            display(node->right);
}

TreeNode *insert(TreeNode *node, const int value){
    if(node == 0)
             return;

    if(node != 0){
        if(value < node->value){
            insert(node->left, value);
        }
        else if(value > node->value){
            insert(node->right, value);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
    node = create_node(value);
    return node;
}

void destroy(TreeNode *node){
    if(node == 0) return;

    destroy(node->left);
    destroy(node->right);
    free(node);
    node = 0;
}
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
./a.out 6 5 
Head node is 5 
4 
4 
5 
6 
6 
7 
8
```

Comment: Your parameter order is reversed. You are using the second argument as the number of nodes and the third as the root value.

Comment: Youre right I will edit this in the post, I just typed it in wrong in the main question, thanks a lot though!

Comment: Your `insert` function only ever changes its own local variable `node` and has no effect on the outside world.

Comment: Do you understand what a segfault *is*? Do you know what a null pointer is? Is there a reason for the first if statement in your insert function?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Don't post your full code next time, try to put just the part that is getting the seg fault. I also added `srand(time(NULL));` to your main to initialize the random number generator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct TreeNode_ {
    int value;
    struct TreeNode_ *left;
    struct TreeNode_ *right;
}TreeNode;


TreeNode* insert(TreeNode* node, const int value);
TreeNode* create_node(const int value);
void destroy(TreeNode* node);
void display(TreeNode* node);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
            if (argc < 3) {
                    printf("%s is missing parameters\n", argv[0]);
                    return 0;
            }

            srand(time(NULL));

            const int size = atoi(argv[1]);
            const int root_val = atoi(argv[2]);
            TreeNode* root = NULL;
            int i;
            root = insert(root,root_val);
            printf("Head node is %d\n", root->value);
            for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                    int value = rand() % 10 + 1;
                    insert(root,value);
            }
            display(root);
            destroy(root);

}

TreeNode *create_node(const int value){

    TreeNode *node;
    node = (TreeNode*)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    node->value = value;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right = NULL;
    return node;

}

void display(TreeNode *node){

    if(node == 0) return;
    if(node->left != 0)
         display(node->left);

    printf("\n%d\n", node->value);

    if(node->right != 0)
            display(node->right);
}

TreeNode * insert(TreeNode *node, const int value){
    if(node == NULL)
        node = create_node(value);

    else if(node != NULL){
            if(value <= node->value){
                    node->left = insert(node->left, value);
            }
            else if(value > node->value){
                    node->right = insert(node->right, value);
            }
    }

    return node;

}

void destroy(TreeNode *node){

    if(node == 0) return;

    destroy(node->left);
    destroy(node->right);
    free(node);
    node = 0;
}
```

Comment: minor BUG _The first one how many nodes_ : You have made ​​the same mistake as OP.